# Redo part of an already committed merge

Tags: git, merge

I have committed a big merge. Later, it appears that some files weren't merged correctly. I want to redo just these files, not the entire merge - the merge was big and I don't want to resolve all the conflicts that were correctly solved already.

If this had occurred before I committed the merge, I could do

```
$ git checkout -m faulty_folder/
```

to reset the faulty merged files to their conflicted state, just like when the merged was started. The problem is that I have committed the merge already, and this command doesn't seem to work anymore.
A simple

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
```

doesn't work either. That really checks out files from `HEAD^`, from before the merge was started.

Is there a way to go back to that merging state?

**Update**

It does not suffice for me to just edit the files to be correct. I would have done that if possible, but I find the merge to be too complicated for that. I need to get a 3-way diff again to be able to solve the conflicts reliably.

Comment: Have you published the branch after completing and committing the merge?

Comment: Yes, but that is not so relevant. I'm currently the only one working on that branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, in fact, simply perform the merge again.  (Be sure you have `git rerere` turned off.)

Remember, `git merge` looks at three things: your current commit, the commit you ask it to merge, and the merge-base of those two commits.  (Well, also your strategy arguments and so on, of course, but you can repeat those as well.)  It's true that you already committed a merge result, but you can still get back on the commit you were on earlier:

```
          o---o---X       <-- otherbranch
         /         \
...--o--*           \ 
         \           \
          o--o--o--Y--M   <-- HEAD -> yourbranch
```

Your merge `M` is the result of merging commits `Y` and `X` (with merge base `*`).  But you can check out commit `Y` as either a detached HEAD or a new branch.  To make a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch yourbranch^
```

which produces:

```
          o---o----X      <-- otherbranch
         /          \
...--o--*            M    <-- yourbranch
         \          /
          o--o--o--Y      <-- HEAD -> newbranch
```

(this is the exact same graph but I moved `M` up a bit to make room for `newbranch` to point to commit `Y`—think of the graph as being kind of rubbery/stretchy, or printed on Play-Doh®, or whatever).  Now you can `git merge otherbranch` and start re-creating commit `M`.

Now you can grab merge results (rather than re-resolving) using `git checkout yourbranch -- path` for various `path`s (even the top path), and optionally `git checkout -m` parts to re-create conflicts.

When you are all done, `git commit` will make a new `M2` merge whose first parent is `Y` and second parent is `X`, and `newbranch` will point to the new merge `M2`.

Comment: This sounds very useful. I'm gonna try this immediately. The fact that you can "grab" merge results from another commit is a simple but smart observation.

Comment: I have to say, I got a `fatal: unable to read blob object a31294ec4a65e446356281e6efadea6e5a0c084a` error message for some directory (not sure why), but for the most part this solution just worked.

Comment: That blob-object issue is concerning, it suggests an integrity problem with your underlying storage (bad bits on disk, in other words).  Might be worth running `git fsck`  to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already pushed the branch after merging, and you suspect that someone else may have pulled it, then you should avoid editing the merge commit.  Instead, you are safest just fixing the files and making a new commit with those changes.

If this be not a concern, then you can try amending the merge commit, assumint that this merge commit is at the `HEAD` of your branch.  Just edit the files which were merged wrongly, test your code, and if you are satisfied, then do an amended commit via:

```
git commit --amend -m 'merge completed successfully'
```

If you now inspect your commit history via `git log`, you will notice that the number of commits is the same as when you first completed the merge.  But the latest commit is *not* the same as the first merge commit.  Rather, it is a completely *new* commit with a new SHA-1 hash.

Comment: @torek For educational purposes, is there anything wrong with just doing a `git commit --amend`?

Comment: I never saw your comment originally, but looked up this question and answers just now and did see it. There's nothing wrong with using `git commit --amend` on a merge (the `--amend` reproduces the previous parents), but it isn't quite what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Since git created a commit that represents your big merge with conflicts you could have just change that commit. To do that, in your working directory, do all the fixes, add to index and amend commit.

```
# do all the fixes
git add .
git commit --amend
```