# All changes overwritten in git

Tags: git, merge

I was working on the `master` branch in our git repo and merged it to our `secondary` branch.

Another developer who's very new to git claims he merged his changes into `secondary` from another branch.

When I pulled the latest changes from the `secondary` branch I see that all of the files and changes I committed with the merge from `master` are all gone now but all of his changes are there after his supposed merge. I can look back at the commits and see that his particular commit did, in fact, remove all of my changes.

He has no idea how he did this and I'm afraid to merge anything from `secondary` to `master` for fear all my changes will be lost.

What is the most likely cause and how can it be corrected so that both our changes are successfully merged instead?

Comment: analyze `git` history

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the same files, it's possible they did the merge with "ours", which takes their changes over what's in the destination branch (your changes). See [git merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies).

Comment: Very few of our files were the same. Even files I newly created were completely deleted.

Comment: @eComEvo (and @Oleksi): if they used the `-s ours` *strategy* (vs the `-X ours` eXtended strategy *option*), that would ignore all the work you, eComEvo, did, while making a merge commit that links back to the commit you made. In other words `-s ours` means "kill the other guy's work entirely".

Comment: @torek I'm really not sure. He uses the Mac app Tower, so this was probably some point and click mishap. If it was what you suggest...how do I undo it and merge both our changes?

Comment: @eComEvo you can revert his merge commit, and try it again, with the right merge options

Comment: Literally undoing a merge is easy but problematic (it's a form of "history rewriting").  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet?rq=1 (but this one is pushed!). Virtually undoing a merge is harder, but not actually *hard*, it's just messy. To completely re-do a merge, as if the original had never happened, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38011005/1256452 - once you're done you can then re-integrate this result back into the branch you want it in.

Comment: I reverted his commit that erased my changes. Now I need to step him thru merging his changes properly into the `secondary` branch.

Answer (score 0):

or he did a git reset hard prior to your commits and started to make his commits? create rules in your git branch vendor or set some best practice convention like no rebasing for shared branches